# HWI Oauth + Symfony 2 /login/check error

Tags: symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

Edit: I moved all of the oauth config in security.yml to the 'default' firewall (and updated the oauth config parameter firewall_main: default in config.yml) and everything started working fine.

I am having an issue with the hwi/oauth-bundle for Symfony. Everything works fine until I am directed back to my site after authenticating on reddit (I also tried twitter as well) at which point I get the error:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login/check-reddit". The route is wrongly configured.
```

I have gone through several docs/tutorials including:

- https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle
- http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony-hwioauthbundle-and-google-sign-in/
- http://www.diegocaprioli.com/adding-hwioauthbundle-to-your-symfony2-project/

From what I can gather it's an issue with /login/check-reddit not being behind a firewall, however, I've tried several tweaks and I just can't seem to get it to work. I've spent nearly 2 hours on this now--if anyone has any direction or suggestions I would be grateful! Thank you.

The relevant code for each of my **routing.yml**, **config.yml**, and **security.yml** can be found below. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

**routing.ytml**

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

reddit_login:
    pattern: /login/check-reddit

twitter_login:
    pattern: /login/check-twitter
```

**config.yml**

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    resource_owners:
        reddit:
            type:                reddit
            client_id:           xxx
            client_secret:       xxx
        twitter:
            type:                twitter
            client_id:           xxx
            client_secret:       xxx
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    twitter:          "/login/check-twitter"
                    reddit:           "/login/check-reddit"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       true
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Did you try putting the same prefix for hwi_oauth_redirect and hwi_oauth_login ? In your case try to put prefix: /login for both. This might fix your problem.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. I switched my firewall to 'default' instead of 'main' and for some reason it started working. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

When i ran into this problem i had to change my routes from login to something else.  so i ended up using "external-login" for my hwi check login routes

**routing.yml**

```
hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /external-login/

reddit_login:
    pattern: /external-login/check-reddit

twitter_login:
    pattern: /external-login/check-twitter
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    twitter:          "/external-login/check-twitter"
                    reddit:           "/external-login/check-reddit"
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting the same error. Did you have to add any additional options to the oauth settings under security?

Comment: if that didn't work then i don't know.  You should try what @HypeR suggested though.

Comment: For some reason if I switched my firewall to 'default' everything worked fine. However, I then ran into issues with reddit login using HWI. I switched to doing it manually since I'll only ever need reddit for this project and it's very straightforward to get a token. Thanks for the suggestion though!